# Best way to handle Null values Moshi-Kotlin/Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I'm using an API to get some recipes for my Application using Retrofit and Moshi. Everything works fine when the values received are not null. A soon as I receive something that is null my whole app stops saying - Missing value was null.

I found this solution on the Web-

```
object NULL_TO_EMPTY_STRING_ADAPTER {
  @FromJson fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): String {
    if (reader.peek() != JsonReader.Token.NULL) {
      return reader.nextString()
    }
    reader.nextNull<Unit>()
    return ""
  }
}
```

If I'm correct, the above adapter returns "" for null values? Since implementing this Adapter my App hasn't crashed. Though, I wanted to ask, what is the best way to handle these null values received from the API.

An Example of one of my Data class is as follows:

```
data class Recipe(
    val vegetarian: Boolean = false,
    val vegan: Boolean = false,
    val glutenFree: Boolean = false,
    val dairyFree: Boolean = false,
    val veryHealthy: Boolean = false,
    val cheap: Boolean = false,
    val veryPopular: Boolean = false,
    val sustainable: Boolean = false,
    val lowFodmap: Boolean = false,
    val weightWatcherSmartPoints: Long = 0L,
    val gaps: String = "",
    val preparationMinutes: Long = 0L,
    val cookingMinutes: Long = 0L,
    val aggregateLikes: Long = 0L,
    val healthScore: Long = 0L,
    val creditsText: String = "",
    val license: String = "",
    val sourceName: String = "",
    val pricePerServing: Double = 0.0,
    val extendedIngredients: List<ExtendedIngredient>? = null,
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val title: String = "",
    val readyInMinutes: Long = 0L,
    val servings: Long = 0L,
    val sourceUrl: String = "",
    val image: String = "",
    val imageType: String = "",
    val summary: String = "",
    val cuisines: List<String> = listOf(""),
    val dishTypes: List<String> = listOf(""),
    val diets: List<String> = listOf(""),
    val occasions: List<String> = listOf(""),
    val instructions: String = "",
    val analyzedInstructions: List<AnalyzedInstruction>? = null,
    val originalId: Any? = null,
    val spoonacularSourceUrl: String = "",
)
```

Before using this NULL_TO_EMPTY_STRING_ADAPTER Adapter, my App would crash when I received a null value from the Server even when I had set my Data Class fields as nullables or with default values.

Please kindly advise as I'm hoping to get my App into production when it is complete. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle null values when using network models in my opinion is by making all the fields nullable. So you are sure that even if that field is null the app wont crash. What you can do is this as a short example.

```
data class Recipe(
    val title: String? = null,
    val vegetarian: Boolean? = false,
    val vegan: Boolean? = false
)

 val recipe = Recipe(null, false, false)
 /*use the title like this*/ recipe.title.orEmpty()
```

`orEmpty()` is an extension function which is String specific that returns the string itself if it is not null or an empty String if the string is null.